# CustomTableView not Displaying contents

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I am new to ObjectiveC and working on a customTableView all was going well until I run the app and no content is displayed except a blanc table with lines across it 
I have tried to find the solution to the problem but so far no luck
below is the code and also the pictures attached

Any help with it will be greatly appreciated

```
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ContactsTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ContactsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *Contact;

@end

@implementation ContactsTableViewController

@synthesize ContactsArray, Contact;


- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

{

self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
{

}

return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Contacts" ofType:@"plist"];

ContactsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

   {

       return [ContactsArray count];
   }

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

    {
            static NSString  *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

        ContactsArray = ContactsArray [indexPath.row];

        NSString *firstName = Contact[@"firstName"];
        NSString *lastName = Contact[@"lastName"];
        NSString *imageName = Contact[@"imageName"];


        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        customCell.CustomFirstNameLabel.text = firstName;
        customCell.CustomLastNameLabel.text= lastName;
        customCell.CustomImageView.image = image;

        return customCell;

     {
```

[Tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJXu9.jpg)

Comment: kindly accept the answer that you think helped you the most!

Comment: Thanks for the info I have just managed to get it working now.  Cesar

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `StackOverflow`.
You can debug this issue in following ways:
 1. Check if `ContactsTableViewController` is a child of `UITableViewController`.
 2. If above is not the case, check the `dataSource` property of your `tableView`.
(something like: `tableView.dataSource = self;`)
 3. Check if your `tableView` is connected to the `Interface Builder` (`xib` or `storyboard`)
 4. Make sure `ContactsTableViewController` implements `UITableViewDataSource`.
 5. Try to NSLog the value of your `ContactsArray`.
 6. And last (but not least) try calling the reloadData method of your tableView after populating your `ContactsArray`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Three issues

- Replace

  ```
  ContactsArray = ContactsArray[indexPath.row];
  ```

  with

  ```
  Contact = ContactsArray[indexPath.row];
  ```
- You have to reload the table view explicitly. Add

  ```
  [tableView reloadData];
  ```

  at the end of `viewDidLoad`.
- You have to cast the custom cell to the actual type

  ```
  CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];
  ```

Further you can delete the entire `initWithStyle` method, since it does nothing actually. And last but not least conform to the naming convention to use variable names starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you for the help I Did the changes suggested but still nothing shows

Comment: Does `ContactsArray` contain the plist data? Is the custom cell class assigned to the cell in Interface Builder? Insert breakpoints or `NSLog` lines to check that.

Comment: Yes it does contain the plist,   and where  would I insert the break points to check that the custom cell class is assigned to the cell in Interface Builder?     Sorry for so many questions

Comment: The breakpoint is not needed for the class check. Select the storyboard and  the table view cell then open the Identity Inspector (⌥⌘3). The custom class field must be `CustomCell`. And check also if the cell view has the proper identifier `Cell`

Comment: Yes it is CustomCell

Comment: it now says  Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: have now found the solution to the scene problem

Comment: If you are using an `UINavigationController` this must be the entry point. You can drag the arrow in Interface Builder. Check also that `datasource` and `delegate` of the `UITableView` instance  are connected to the table view controller.